# How to translate "ernsten Oper" in Nietzsche

Tags: translation

— Sehr verschieden steht es mit der **ernsten Oper**:

'Serious opera' or 'dramatic opera'? Or *opera seria*? Or 'tragic opera'?

He mentions Rossini, whose operas date from the early 19th century.

Here is the whole passage, if that helps:

80 - Kunst und Natur.— Die Griechen (oder wenigstens die Athener) hörten gerne gut reden: ja sie hatten einen gierigen Hang darnach, der sie mehr als alles Andere von den Nicht-Griechen unterscheidet. Und so verlangten sie selbst von der Leidenschaft auf der Bühne, dass sie gut rede, und liessen die Unnatürlichkeit des dramatischen Verses mit Wonne über sich ergehen:—in der Natur ist ja die Leidenschaft so wortkarg! so stumm und verlegen! Oder wenn sie Worte findet, so verwirrt und unvernünftig und sich selber zur Scham! Nun haben wir uns Alle, Dank den Griechen, an diese Unnatur auf der Bühne gewöhnt, wie wir jene andere Unnatur, die singende Leidenschaft ertragen und gerne ertragen, Dank den Italiänern.— Es ist uns ein Bedürfniss geworden, welches wir aus der Wirklichkeit nicht befriedigen können: Menschen in den schwersten Lagen gut und ausführlich reden zu hören: es entzückt uns jetzt, wenn der tragische Held da noch Worte, Gründe, beredte Gebärden und im Ganzen eine helle Geistigkeit findet, wo das Leben sich den Abgründen nähert, und der wirkliche Mensch meistens den Kopf und gewiss die schöne Sprache verliert. Diese Art Abweichung von der Natur ist vielleicht die angenehmste Mahlzeit für den Stolz des Menschen; ihretwegen überhaupt liebt er die Kunst, als den Ausdruck einer hohen, heldenhaften Unnatürlichkeit und Convention. Man macht mit Recht dem dramatischen Dichter einen Vorwurf daraus, wenn er nicht Alles in Vernunft und Wort verwandelt, sondern immer einen Rest Schweigen in der Hand zurückbehält:—so wie man mit dem Musiker der Oper unzufrieden ist, der für den höchsten Affect nicht eine Melodie, sondern nur ein affectvolles "natürliches" Stammeln und Schreien zu finden weiss. Hier soll eben der Natur widersprochen werden! Hier soll eben der gemeine Reiz der Illusion einem höheren Reize weichen! Die Griechen gehen auf diesem Wege weit, weit—zum Erschrecken weit! Wie sie die Bühne so schmal wie möglich bilden und alle Wirkung durch tiefe Hintergründe sich verbieten, wie sie dem Schauspieler das Mienenspiel und die leichte Bewegung unmöglich machen und ihn in einen feierlichen, steifen, maskenhaften Popanz verwandeln, so haben sie auch der Leidenschaft selber den tiefen Hintergrund genommen und ihr ein Gesetz der schönen Rede dictirt, ja sie haben überhaupt Alles gethan, um der elementaren Wirkung furcht- und mitleiderweckender Bilder entgegenzuwirken: sie wollten eben nicht Furcht und Mitleid,—Aristoteles in Ehren und höchsten Ehren! aber er traf sicherlich nicht den Nagel, geschweige den Kopf des Nagels, als er vom letzten Zweck der griechischen Tragödie sprach! Man sehe sich doch die griechischen Dichter der Tragödie darauf hin an, was am Meisten ihren Fleiss, ihre Erfindsamkeit, ihren Wetteifer erregt hat,—gewiss nicht die Absicht auf Ueberwältigung der Zuschauer durch Affecte! Der Athener gieng in's Theater, um schöne Reden zu hören! Und um schöne Reden war es dem Sophokles zu thun!—man vergebe mir diese Ketzerei!— Sehr verschieden steht es mit der **ernsten Oper**: alle ihre Meister lassen es sich angelegen sein, zu verhüten, dass man ihre Personen verstehe. Ein gelegentlich aufgerafftes Wort mag dem unaufmerksamen Zuhörer zu Hülfe kommen: im Ganzen muss die Situation sich selber erklären,—es liegt Nichts an den Reden!—so denken sie Alle und so haben sie Alle mit den Worten ihre Possen getrieben. Vielleicht hat es ihnen nur an Muth gefehlt, um ihre letzte Geringschätzung des Wortes ganz auszudrücken: ein wenig Frechheit mehr bei Rossini und er hätte durchweg la-la-la-la singen lassen—und es wäre Vernunft dabei gewesen! Es soll den Personen der Oper eben nicht "auf's Wort" geglaubt werden, sondern auf den Ton! Das ist der Unterschied, das ist die schöne Unnatürlichkeit, derentwegen man in die Oper geht! Selbst das recitativo secco will nicht eigentlich als Wort und Text angehört sein: diese Art von Halbmusik soll vielmehr dem musicalischen Ohre zunächst eine kleine Ruhe geben (die Ruhe von der Melodie, als dem sublimsten und desshalb auch anstrengendsten Genusse dieser Kunst)—, aber sehr bald etwas Anderes: nämlich eine wachsende Ungeduld, ein wachsendes Widerstreben, eine neue Begierde nach ganzer Musik, nach Melodie.— Wie verhält es sich, von diesem Gesichtspuncte aus gesehen, mit der Kunst Richard Wagner's? Vielleicht anders? Oft wollte es mir scheinen, als ob man Wort und Musik seiner Schöpfungen vor der Aufführung auswendig gelernt haben müßte: denn ohne diess—so schien es mir—höre man weder die Worte noch selber die Musik.

In a prior section he mentions Bellini along with Rossini:

77 - Das Thier mit gutem Gewissen.— Das Gemeine in Alledem, was im Süden Europa's gefällt—sei diess nun die italiänische Oper (zum Beispiel Rossini's und Bellini's) oder der spanische Abenteuer-Roman (uns in der französischen Verkleidung des Gil Blas am besten zugänglich)—bleibt mir nicht verborgen, aber es beleidigt mich nicht, ebensowenig als die Gemeinheit, der man bei einer Wanderung durch Pompeji und im Grunde selbst beim Lesen jedes antiken Buches begegnet: woher kommt diess?

77- The animal with good conscience — I am not unacquainted with the fact that there is something vulgar in everything that appeals to Southern Europeans — whether it be Italian opera (for example, Rossini’s and Bellini’s), or the Spanish adventure-novel (most readily accessible to us in the French garb of Gil Blas ) — but it does not offend me, any more than the vulgarity which one encounters in a walk through Pompeii, or even in the reading of any ancient book. Why is this so?

Comment: According to your quote, i would use "serious opera". But probably this would change if your quote would be longer.

Comment: I think it tries to say "not comedy", but not sure which word is the best here...

Comment: Can you deduce from the context what Nietzsche refers to? If he means "serious Italian-language opera till 1800 or so", then "opera seria" is in fact the standard term. If he means anything more general, I'd prefer "serious opera" or "dramatic opera". Without the context, I can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the full paragraph, I don't have the impression that he uses "ernste Oper" in the narrow sense of "opera seria". Rossini is definitely not "opera seria"; I wouldn't even call most of his music "ernst". "Serious opera" or "dramatic opera" is fine. Perhaps also "Italian opera" or "bel canto style opera", since Nietzsche contrasts it with Wagner later.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but to clarify that we need to establish some historical context first. The meaning of this single word cannot be "translated" without explaining the (cultural and music-historical) background upon which this meaning unfolds. Bear with me:

The musical form of "opera" started to evolve at about 1600 in Florence. Arguably the first work to be called "opera" was *Jacopo Peris* "[La Dafne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dafne)" (1598), but perhaps Peri was soon surpassed by *Claudio Monteverdi* (i.e. "[L'Orfeo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Orfeo)", 1607), whose operas made use of a larger orchestra, enriched harmonics, a characteristic instrumentation for the respective roles, etc.. Also the "aria" (in opposition to the *recitar cantando*, a more spoken than sung piece) as we know it today is an invention by Monteverdi.

The driving force behind the formation of the opera was the florentinian *Camerata*, an academic discussion cirle of humanists who tried to revive the antique (greek) *drama* - or, rather, what they thought the greek drama was.

Perhaps the most important tenet of the *Camerata* was that *text* - especially sung text - had to be *understandable*. For instance, *[Giulio Caccini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giulio_Caccini)* mentioned in "Le Nouve Musiche" (1601) a "nobile sprezzatura di canto" (about: "noble disregard of singing", for details about the word "sprezzatura" see [B. Castiglione](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprezzatura)). This is perhaps what Nietzsche referred to when he writes:

> [...]gewiss nicht die Absicht auf Ueberwältigung der Zuschauer durch Affecte! Der Athener gieng in's Theater, um schöne Reden zu hören!

And:

> Es soll den Personen der Oper eben nicht "auf's Wort" geglaubt werden, sondern auf den Ton! Das ist der Unterschied, das ist die schöne Unnatürlichkeit, derentwegen man in die Oper geht!

Or, in other words: should *arias* be a more or less spoken text with some musical ornamentation (like, as the *Camerata* thought [and Nietzsche agreed], was the way the greek *drama* did it) or should *arias* be pieces of music first and foremost and the understandability of the text be considered less important compared to i.e. the quality of the voice, intonation, etc.. Or, to put in flapsy words: should opera be considered *literature with some music* or *music with some text*?

In the 18th century two types of operas started to form: the *opera seria* and the *opera buffa*. (Notice that "opera seria" as a term was not commonly used until after the form went out of fashion.)

The *Opera seria* was an already established genre and was mostly done for the representation and legitimation of the nobility. The *libretto* vas invariably in Italian and the plot was usually taken from greek mythology. There is a strong distinction between *recitativ* - the part where the story line is developed and dialogue happens - and the *aria*, which mostly contains "static" commentary to the story line.

At about middle of the 19th century we see the *recitative* being replaced (especially in the "[number opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_opera)") by completely composed pieces. Wagner was one of the proponents of this development. The common form of the *recitativo secco* (sometimes *recitativo semplice*), the "simple/dry recitative" is replaced by the *recitativo accompagnato* or simply "accompagnato". This process started as early as with Bach (i.e. "Die Matthäuspassion", where Jesus is pictured by accopagnato-recitatives) and contiued with Glucks and Salieris operas, but the *recitativo secco* can be seen as late as 1840 (Verdi, "Un giorno di regno").

So, to sum it up: "ernste Oper" could be translated by "opera seria", because this is the name of the genre Nietzsche talks about here. The "opera seria" usually doesn't end tragically (as the name might imply), in fact a "happy end" often takes place to emphasize the victory (and also the reward) of virtue.

What Nietzsche talks about in general in the quoted part is a critique about Wagner and his way of composing operas, in specific about his style of replacing the *recitativo secco* by *accompagnato*.